# How to have a working google sheets script, that only runs on empty cells leaving other cells intact

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that currently works but not how I would like.

this copies data from column B to G that contains formulas pulling information from openweathermap.org and pastes the values of the formula in to columns H to L. The reason I run this script is that the formula from openweathermap.org updates. I want the script to only run on empty cells leaving cells that already contain data in Columns H to L alone. (So they only paste values once)

I am new to Google script and have researched on google but cannot find a previous result that works for my script

I expect the code to run and copy and data but to ignore any cells in Columns H to L if it contains data

Script

```
function moveValuesOnly1() {var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getRange("Sheet1!B:G"); 
source.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet1!H:L"),
 {contentsOnly: true});}
```

I expect the code to run and copy and data but to ignore any cells in Columns H to L if it contains data

Comment: The ranges are not the same size.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your asking.  For example, what if there is data in destination range where I might put data from the source.  What should the code do with the source data.

Comment: Perhaps you just want to append new data below the old data in the destination range.

Comment: Apologies the copy range is H:M

Comment: I have a google form that when completed saves to a google sheet, I have preset formulas that take the town name from the form entry to provide me with the weather. Which is on columns B:G. The script then saves the formula as a value to H:M as the weather formula constantly updates. I do not want the script to update cells it has already converted, therefore only run on blank cells. Hopefully this makes more sense

Comment: And do you wish to append all of the new data below the old data or if they are intertwined then how does that happen.

Comment: Sorry I don’t know what you mean, I want the old data to stay as is, and new data to be underneath

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a lot harder then I thought it was going to be.

Try this:

```
function moveValuesOnly1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var srg=sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),6);
  var vA=srg.getValues();
  sh.getRange(getLastRowOfRange("H:M")+1,8,srg.getHeight(),srg.getWidth()).setValues(vA);
}


function getLastRowOfRange(A1Range) {
  var A1Range=A1Range||"H:M";//default for debugging
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(A1Range);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=vA.length-1;i>-1;i--) {
    if(vA[i].join("").length==0) {
      vA.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(vA.length);
  return vA.length;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it has not quiet worked how I wanted. the above actually showed an error. I changed it slightly and it did work but not how I wanted. to re-explain to see if I can make this easier. I want the script to copy cells B to G and place them as 'values' in H to M, however not to copy every cell. So for example, if rows 2-5 have run the script once, I would have data showing in B2 to B5 through to G2 to G5. I would then have a copy of that data in H2 through to M5. if new data was put in to rows 5-10 I do not want the script to run any data from B2 - G5. I hope this helps.

Comment: The idea would just be to copy new data. Leaving previous data intact, not copying the whole data from B:G every time. Thank you for helping.